# Windows 7 Professional or Windows Small Business Server 2011

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

If a user just simply needs a file server for 6 people, and to connect to a shared printer, is Windows 7 going to be enough? I know Windows 7 allows for 20 connections, which should be enough for this scenario. Seeing the price difference, I want to know if it is actually worthwhile getting a SBS server instead

Comment: SBS has the ability to backup clients.  it really depends on your plan usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 Pro should be sufficient.  The value SBS provides is getting cost effective Exchange services along side with better WWW services.  If you don't suspect that will need to provide web services or exchange, stick to Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Win7 is sufficient. You might consider having the shared drive be separate from the primary system drive so that it doesn't slow the local user down too much if it's heavily used.

Comment: Should have clarified: It will be a stand-alone computer, used as a server and that's it

Comment: If you only need a file share, consider a cheap mirrored NAS instead.

Comment: It will need to run another program as well, which will be independent of Windows as a workstation or as a server. If it was strictly for file sharing, then yes, I would agree